# SQL Calculate Converted Value using Exchange Rate Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I was given two hypothetical tables

Orders:

Customer_ID, Order_ID, Order_date, Sales_in_USD

Exchange_Rate:

From_Currency, To_Currency, Effective_Date, Exchange_Rate

Example:  If a currency is stated in USD and we wish to convert to EUR then the From_Currency would be “USD” and the To_Currency would be “EUR”

There could be many instances where From_Currency would be “USD” and the To_currency would be “EUR”. I need to select the rate that would have been in effect for a given date. For example, if I have an order_date of 12/14/2018, I must use the exchange rate with an effective date that is closest to 12/14/2018 and the effective date must be on the same day or prior to 12/14/2018.  Also, keep in mind there might not be.

How to write a query which will show all columns in the Orders table and an additional column which shows Sales_in_USD converted to EUR?

Comment: Do you have currencies other than USD and EUR in your table? it's better to post a sample of your tables and the expected output.

Comment: It's a hypothetical question. There is no table. Hypothetically, there are other currencies in the table

Comment: First, always use the appropriate tags (you have both mysql and sql-server tagged - assuming you're not developing this for both). Second, you can create an exchange rate table (as you mentioned) that gets updated at least once a day (from an outside source/API - which is an entirely different topic to be maintained). Then, create a function to pass in the to/from currency, and date from your target table to retrieve the appropriate rate from the exchange rate table.